# Analogue of Baer's Criterion for Projective Modules

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module

It is well-known that by Baer's Criterion, for a $R$-module $Q$, $\text{Hom}(-,Q)$ is exact (i.e. $Q$ is injective) if and only if resulting sequence of this functor act on exact sequence
$$0\rightarrow I\rightarrow R\rightarrow R/I\rightarrow0$$
is exact for any left ideal $I$.

Then is it true for analogous (or, in some sense, dual) statement that for a $R$-module $P$, $\text{Hom}(P,-)$ is exact (i.e. $P$ is projective) if and only if it is exact on special exact sequence shown above?

In fact my friend guess this is not true for some reason that I don't know. However, I can't find any counterexamples of this. So if there exist any counterexample please show me.

Also, If this is false, then is there exist some criterion for projectivity analogous to Baer's criterion? More precisely, is there exist certain class of exact sequence, depend on $R$, such that $\text{Hom}(P,-)$ is exact in that sequences implies projectivity?

Comment: Maybe this helps answer your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124301/baers-criterion-for-projective-modules.

Comment: This is [a duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/789488/29335) although there is not really a satisfactory answer there.  I have discussed this with others before. As I remember, the naive analogue is false. Someone once told me some good conditions on the ring to make it true, but I have forgotten them... I will let you know if I find the notes.

Comment: @Batominovski Ah right, the Trlifaj paper was definitely the one. I *thought* perfectness was the key.